# adding executable file to path and launching from terminal directly

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, bashrc, paths

i just downloaded sublime text for my ubuntu, and its working fine. i have the executable file in my

> ~/sublime

folder. now i would like to invoke this app from the terminal by just typing sublime. i suppose that is possible, pls let me know how.

also, since this application did not need any configure/make/install (i just had to extract it and then use the exec file to run the app), i cannot add this to my gnome launcher fav apps panel. how can i put the app shortcut there, so that when i do a top-left and then type sublime, the results will show the applicaion and then i can click on it and invoke the app from there?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To answer it in simple way.

If you have installed the sublime app using ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

then you can invoke the app using `sublime` through the command in terminal.

But if you have downloaded the **.tar.gz** file from [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) then you have to create a **.desktop** file invoke from unity launcher or create a alias and invoke from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a soft symbol link

```
$ sudo ln -s ~/sublime /usr/bin/sublime
```

Please refer to [this blog](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/) for more detailed information.

An great alternative for Ubuntu Sublime text users is use a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/sublime-text-2) provided by WebUpd8 team.

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

After installation, you can use *subl* or *subl-text* from the terminal.

Comment: on a different note, in the link that u provided in the above response, in step4, i see that they are using the SyntaxHighlighter developed by Alex. Is there some way i can use it with Sublime also, just to change the look and feel? I really like how the code looks with that SyntaxHighlighter tool. thanks!

Comment: sorry @ubunnttuu , I am not familiar with SyntaxHighlighter tool. Hope you have solved this problem.